# WiX: Preserve on major upgrade, remove on uninstall

Tags: upgrade, uninstallation

I have defined a component to cleanup a generated (not installed) file on uninstall but leave intact on a major upgrade after reading this post

```
<Component Id="C_RemoveOnUninstall" Guid="XXX">
  <RemoveFile Id="DeleteGeneratedFile" Name="ProgramGeneratedFile" On="uninstall"/>
  <Condition>REMOVE="ALL" AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Condition>
</Component>
```

With condition above, the file is left behind for both upgrade and uninstall. 
Without the condition, the file is deleted for both upgrade and uinstall.

I have tried RemoveFile for each of On="install/uninstall/both" but it does not seem to matter. Have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488620/wix-major-upgrade) but I am hoping to make component conditions work and avoid writing custom action for this.

Does this code look correct? Any solutions or work around?

Comment: Have you tried marking the component as transitive=yes? Without this I suspect the component condition won't get re-evaluated when you go into maintenance mode (i.e. when you run the nested uninstall as part of upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes the [RemoveFiles action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ignores an item in the [RemoveFile table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when the property DirProperty referrers to has a value of null.  The property DirProperty referrers to will be set during uninstall though not during an upgrade.

Conditionally set the property:

```
<SetProperty Id="prop_GeneratedFileDir" Value="[GeneratedFileDir]" After="InstallInitialize" Sequence="execute">
  REMOVE="ALL" AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE
</SetProperty>
```

Define an element for the RemoveFile table:

```
<Component Id="C_RemoveOnUninstall" Guid="XXX">
  <RemoveFile Id="DeleteGeneratedFile" Property="prop_GeneratedFileDir" Name="ProgramGeneratedFile" On="uninstall"/>
  <CreateFolder/>
</Component>
```

Some helpful links:
  [wix-users](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg48212.html), [RemoveFile Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [RemoveFile Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_removefile.htm), [RemoveFolderEx Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_removefolderex.htm)